# How to create two buttons based on separate id's

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I am trying to create two buttons, based on if a certain condition is met. I am doing something wrong and only one button get created, and it's the wrong one to begin with.

There is a condition called `onDuty` that is true when a member of a team is on duty. A member can be in many teams and a team can hold many members. So, als long as a member of a team is not on duty (`onDuty = false`) I want to display a button for him to be able to asign duty to himself.

Below is what I have been trying to do so far:

```
    $user = User::find()->where(['user.iduser' => Yii::$app->user->identity->iduser])->all();
    foreach ($user as $team) {
        $userTeams = $team->teamIdteams;
        foreach ($userTeams as $teams) {
            $teamId = $teams->idteam;
        }
        $userAndTeam = UserAndTeams::find()->where(['userid' => Yii::$app->user->identity->iduser])->andWhere(['teamid'=>$teamId])->all();
        foreach ($userAndTeam as $userAndTeams) {
            // Here I fail to get it done correctly.
            if ($userAndTeams->onduty !== true) {
                echo Html::a('<span class="btn-label">'.$teams->name.'</span>', 
               ['activate', 'id' => Yii::$app->user->identity->iduser, 'team' => $teamId],
               ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. I am an idiot sometimes...

```
$user = User::find()->where(['user.iduser' => Yii::$app->user->identity->iduser])->all();
    foreach ($user as $team) {
        $userTeams = $team->teamIdteams;
        foreach ($userTeams as $teams) {
            $teamId = $teams->idteam;
            $userAndTeam = UserAndTeams::find()->where(['userid' => Yii::$app->user->identity->iduser])->andWhere(['teamid'=>$teamId])->all();
            foreach ($userAndTeam as $userAndTeams) {
                // Here I fail to get it done correctly.
                if ($userAndTeams->onduty !== true) {
                    echo Html::a('<span class="btn-label">'.$teams->name.'</span>', 
                   ['activate', 'id' => Yii::$app->user->identity->iduser, 'team' => $teamId],
                   ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```